# Channel dimension Found 'None', however through tensor.get_shape() it has been defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I get to a problem when I'm trying to concatenate some same shape of tensor together to process through some operation (some fully connected layer etc.)
I concatenate them as followed:

```
x_con = KL.concatenate([x1, x2, x3, x4], axis=-1,name='P3_concatenate')
x=Squeeze_excitation(x_con, origin_x=x, out_dim=256 * 4, ratio=16, layer_name='x_con')
```

and the Squeeze_exicitation is the function where I defined the processing with the tensor:

```
def Squeeze_excitation(input_x, origin_x, out_dim, ratio, layer_name):
    print("input shape:",input_x.get_shape().as_list())
    squeeze = KL.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name=layer_name+'_Squeeze_Layer')(input_x)

    excitation = KL.Dense(units=out_dim // ratio, name=layer_name + '_fully_connected1')(squeeze)

    excitation = KL.Activation('relu',name=layer_name+'_relu')(excitation)
    excitation = KL.Dense(units=out_dim, name=layer_name + '_fully_connected2')(excitation)

    excitation = KL.Activation('sigmoid', name=layer_name+'_sigmoid')(excitation)

    excitation = KL.Reshape((1, 1, out_dim))(excitation)
    print("exicitation shape:", excitation.get_shape().as_list())

    scale = KL.multiply([input_x,excitation], name=layer_name+'_multiply')
    print("scale shape:",scale.get_shape().as_list())

    index = K.constant(value=out_dim//4,dtype=tf.int32)
    scale = KL.add([scale[:, :, :, 0:index], scale[:, :, :, index:2 * index],
                    scale[:, :, :, 2 * index:3 * index], scale[:, :, :, 3 * index:]],name=layer_name+'_Add_n')
    print("scale shape:", scale.get_shape().as_list())

    return scale
```

After the processing of the tensor, I try to add a convolutional layer to this tensor:

```
x = KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="SAME")(x)
```

and it raised an error:

```
ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found `None`.
```

To check with the dimensions of the tensor when processing with it, I add some output to keep an eye with its dimension, here is the output in the function Squueze_excitation:

```
input shape: [None, 32, 32, 1024]
exicitation shape: [None, 1, 1, 1024]
scale shape: [None, 32, 32, 1024]
scale shape: [None, 32, 32, 256]
```

I got no clue how to deal with this problem, can somebody help me out of here? 
P.S.If there is anything not clear about the discription of the problem here, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by finding that it was cause by the variable index, which is a keras.constant, I change it to :

```
scale = KL.Lambda(lambda inputs: KL.Add()([inputs[:, :, :, 0:256], inputs[:, :, :, 256:512],
                    inputs[:, :, :, 512:768], inputs[:, :, :, 768:]]))(scale)
```

which means I wrapped it with Lambda Layer in Keras. And I removed the variable index here.